# Safari is not displaying background images

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script

I've searched and found numerous answers, nothing seems to work. I have a table with 3 submit buttons. I need background images on these buttons. I have tried just adding

```
background:url(https://docs.google.com/a/mancino.ca/uc?id=0B15Sq4XXVbGIZm1jVG9xejA1TkE&amp;export=download);
```

just by itself, nothing else, I've tried adding a `z-index` of `-1`, tried removing the `no-repeat` and creating a seperate line for it.

```
background-repeat:no-repeat;
```

As I've said just the url alone won't work, I've tried adding a style with bg image to the `td` tag too. I'm angry and disappointed that I am having such a huge trouble. One final thing to note I am developing an app on google apps using google script to iframe all this html. Last note. yes I did try to add '' around the url.

```
<td style="width:60px">
<div style="text-align:left"><input onclick="document.itemForm.pressed.value=this.id;" type="submit" id="search" value="" style="width:250px; height:250px; background:url(https://docs.google.com/a/mancino.ca/uc?id=0B15Sq4XXVbGIZm1jVG9xejA1TkE&amp;export=download); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position:center; z-index: -1;" alt="SEARCH"></div>
</td>
<td style="width:60px">
<div style="text-align:left"><input onclick="document.itemForm.pressed.value=this.id;" type="submit" id="edit" value="" style="width:250px; height:250px; background:url(https://docs.google.com/a/mancino.ca/uc?id=0B15Sq4XXVbGIM0luZ2FPN1ktODA&amp;export=download) no-repeat; background-position:center;" alt="EDIT"></div>
</td>
<td style="width:60px">
<div style="text-align:left"><input onclick="document.itemForm.pressed.value=this.id;" type="submit" id="add" value="" style="width:250px; height:250px; background:url(https://docs.google.com/a/mancino.ca/uc?id=0B15Sq4XXVbGIWWt2TGxnVzFBT1U&amp;export=download) no-repeat; background-position:center;" alt="ADD"></div>
</td>
```

Comment: Oh and the entire thing is working and tested on the page. image was added last, works in chrome on Mac, not on iPhone or iPad. Also tested my safari(iOS and Mac) with no luck. It really sucks because it's intended for use with an iPad.

Comment: It's something with your url. I took your code and replaced only the image url and everything works fine. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xtaoqo8a/)

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to link from a google drive file.  I believe that's where your issues are coming from.